# Ember.js access multiple models in a template with selectlist

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a challenge I cannot get around:

- I can't populate the selectlist with another model then article
- I have on template 'article' and use the same article view for creating new articles is that possible with the same select?

I hope someone has experience with it?

I have the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="article">
    Name: {{name}}
    Landcodes: {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="model.landcode" 
                 optionLabelPath="content.code optionValuePath="content.id"}}
</script>
```

**Model**

```
App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
    naam: DS.attr('string'),
    landcode: DS.hasMany('landcode')
});
App.Landcode = DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Router**

```
// for editing an existing article
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('article', params.id);
    }
});

// for creating a new article
App.ArticleNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function () { // using the same template as article
        this.render('article', {
            controller: 'article.new'
        });
    },
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('article');
    } 
});
```

Edit: updated jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/4/edit?html,js,output
Edit 2: latest working Ember.Select with a working selected option from model: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/11/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want to share a template across multiple templates you should use a partial, but in your particular case I believe you should use a needs and access the model/controller from a different route.

In the example below I have the post route which has a list of colors, then if you click the `create New` link it will take you to the post.new route.  The post.new route also shows that same list of colors, but it's grabbing that list from the post route.  In the PostNewController I've added a property `needs` and set it to `post`.  This tells ember that the post.new controller needs the post controller.  Now inside the post.new controller I can access the post controller using `controllers.post.******`.  I did this when creating the select in the post.new template.

```
 {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controllers.post.colors"  
   optionLabelPath="content.color" optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/1/edit

Here's an example based on your jsbin below.  The trick is to setup the controller manually if it isn't in the route at any point.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/10/edit

Comment: I think we are really close. See my edited jsbin that better suite the example I gave because I do not get the select working: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/4/edit?html,js,output Everything is in place, and everything works, except: 1) to popuplate the select and 2) of course selecting the selected element does also not work because of point 1.

Comment: Hi, I changed the JS Bin a bit because I edited my API. Now it does not always return an array of ids for belongsTo items. So here is the correct bin I am working with: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/7/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies how to get the landcode data there. I have one small update on your jsbin, that is 'value' property of the Ember.Select. So now the landcode from the Article model is the selected one in the Ember.Select: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/11/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

I find a couple of probz with your bin.

When you have a route named `landcodes` then a controller with a same name `App.LandcodesController` (Might be ObjectController/ArrayController/Controller depending upon the model) is generated by ember if you did not create one explicitly. So you should mention
`landcodes` while specifying the `needs`

The Route's afterModel/model/beforeModel hooks will be called only when you make a transition to the route. Since you didn't make to visit to `landcodes`, the content is not setup in the controller. Hence the select cant populate the content that was not resolved

Comment: If you make a transition to `landcodes`, the content will be populated http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aJATOhEp/9/edit

Comment: Hi selva-G, you are making a good point about the need of calling the Landcodes Route! But now the question is, is there a way to call the model hook from the Article Route or Article Controller? So the Landcodes can be accessed by the Article Route (template).